# Can't find elements in html using webdriverio with phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, webdriver-io

We have an angular based app, and can't find the dynamic elements by id.

We refered to https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/585

and resized the window but no joy?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with not rendered element/class.

There are two options:

- add [pause](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/pause.html);
- or, write custom waiter - [WAITUNTIL](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitUntil.html).

I'd highly recommend the second option.